# Linq late binding confusion

Tags: c#, linq

Can someone please explain me what I am missing here. Based on my basic understanding linq result will be calculated when the result will be used and I can see that in following code.

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
 {
     Action<IEnumerable<int>> print = (x) =>
     {
         foreach (int i in x)
         {
             Console.WriteLine(i);
         }
     };

     int[] arr = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
     int cutoff = 1;
     IEnumerable<int> result = arr.Where(x => x < cutoff);
     Console.WriteLine("First Print");
     cutoff = 3;
     print(result);
     Console.WriteLine("Second Print");
     cutoff = 4;
     print(result);
     Console.Read();
}
```

**Output:**

```
First Print
1
2
Second Print
1
2
3
```

Now I changed the

```
arr.Where(x => x < cutoff);
```

to

```
IEnumerable<int> result = arr.Take(cutoff);
```

and the output is as follow.

```
First Print
1
Second Print
1
```

Why with Take, it does not use the current value of the variable?

Comment: It has nothing to do with late binding...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a few different things getting confused here.

**Late-binding**: This is where the meaning of code is determined after it was compiled. For example, `x.DoStuff()` is early-bound if the compiler checks that objects of `x`'s type have a `DoStuff()` method (considering extension methods and default arguments too) and then produces the call to it in the code it outputs, or fails with a compiler error otherwise. It is late-bound if the search for the `DoStuff()` method is done at run-time and throws a run-time exception if there was no `DoStuff()` method. There are pros and cons to each, and C# is normally early-bound but has support for late-binding (most simply through `dynamic` but the more convoluted approaches involving reflection also count).

**Delayed execution**: Strictly speaking, all Linq methods immediately produce a result. However, that result is an object which stores a reference to an enumerable object (often the result of the previous Linq method) which it will process in an appropriate manner when it is itself enumerated. For example, we can write our own `Take` method as:

```
private static IEnumerable<T> TakeHelper<T>(IEnumerable<T> source, int number)
{
  foreach(T item in source)
  {
    yield return item;
    if(--number == 0)
      yield break;
  }
}
public static IEnumerable<T> Take<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int number)
{
  if(source == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException();
  if(number < 0)
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
  if(number == 0)
    return Enumerable.Empty<T>();
  return TakeHelper(source, number);
}
```

Now, when we use it:

```
var taken4 = someEnumerable.Take(4);//taken4 has a value, so we've already done
                                    //something. If it was going to throw
                                    //an argument exception it would have done so
                                    //by now.

var firstTaken = taken4.First();//only now does the object in taken4
                                        //do the further processing that iterates
                                        //through someEnumerable.
```

**Captured variables**: Normally when we make use of a variable, we make use of how its current state:

```
int i = 2;
string s = "abc";
Console.WriteLine(i);
Console.WriteLine(s);
i = 3;
s = "xyz";
```

It's pretty intuitive that this prints `2` and `abc` and not `3` and `xyz`. In anonymous functions and lambda expressions though, when we make use of a variable we are "capturing" it as a variable, and so we will end up using the value it has when the delegate is invoked:

```
int i = 2;
string s = "abc";
Action λ = () =>
{
  Console.WriteLine(i);
  Console.WriteLine(s);
};
i = 3;
s = "xyz";
λ();
```

Creating the `λ` doesn't use the values of `i` and `s`, but creates a set of instructions as to what to do with `i` and `s` when `λ` is invoked. Only when that happens are the values of `i` and `s` used.

**Putting it all together**: In none of your cases do you have any late-binding. That is irrelevant to your question.

In both you have delayed execution. Both the call to `Take` and the call to `Where` return enumerable objects which will act upon `arr` when they are enumerated.

In only one do you have a captured variable. The call to `Take` passes an integer directly to `Take` and `Take` makes use of that value. The call to `Where` passes a `Func<int, bool>` created from a lambda expression, and that lambda expression captures an `int` variable. `Where` knows nothing of this capture, but the `Func` does.

That's the reason the two behave so differently in how they treat `cutoff`.

Comment: Thanks Jon. I knew about the late binding but I was working on multiple things and used the wrong term there instead of delayed execution. But Still it was kind of fun to read your answer. Thanks man.

Comment: In your example implementation of `Take`, the argument exception would NOT be thrown where you indicate.  None of the code you wrote runs until the first MoveNext.  You need to have an outer method do the parameter validation and call a helper method written with the yields.

Comment: @GideonEngelberth Thanks for the catch. I wanted to be concise since it's intended to be read rather than run, but it rather defeated my very point as written. Taking a closer look at the real thing, I realise that it should just treat negative numbers as zero, but I think I'll leave that bug in there as it doesn't defeat my argument.

Answer (score 6):

The behavior your seeing comes from the different way in which the arguments to the LINQ functions are evaluated.  The `Where` method recieves a lambda which captures the value `cutoff` by reference.  It is evaluated on demand and hence sees the value of `cutoff` at that time.

The `Take` method (and similar methods like `Skip`) take an `int` parameter and hence `cutoff` is passed by value.  The value used is the value of `cutoff` at the moment the `Take` method is called, not when the query is evaluated

Note: The term late binding here is a bit incorrect.  Late binding generally refers to the process where the members an expression binds to are determined at runtime vs. compile time.  In C# you'd accomplish this with `dynamic` or reflection.  The behavior of LINQ to evaluate it's parts on demand is known as delayed execution.

Answer (score 1):

`Take` doesn't take a lambda, but an integer, as such it can't change when you change the original variable.